# creating / formating JSON to retrieve more pages R

Tags: json, r

I need to be able to format or recreate json file that I'm able to change page part of the json. Json has weird structure, that I'm not able to recreate. Here is JSON part:

```
library(jsonlite)

dput(json)
"{\"page\": 0,\"selections\": [{\"systemBetType\": \"SYSTEM\",\"outcomes\": [{\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"tie\": {\"selected\": true},\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"tie\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"tie\": {\"selected\": true},\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"tie\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"away\": {\"selected\": true}},\n    {\"home\": {\"selected\": true},\"tie\": {\"selected\": true},\"away\": {\"selected\": true}}]}]}"
```

Reason for me trying to recreate this is that website has more pages (url response has MORE PAGES = TRUE, so I would need to be able to change page from 0 to 1 and so on, if needed. There can be thousands of pages, so I don't want to create json for each one by hand. Here is what I think is needed to recreate this in R:

```
page <- 0
systemBetType <- "SYSTEM"
away <- data.frame(selected = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE))
home <- data.frame(selected = c(NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
tie <- data.frame(selected = c(NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE))
```

Format of the JSON is just too weird as I think there is data.frame inside data.frame. My idea now is to create some kind of function with while loop (while response MORE PAGES = TRUE then page + 1 and run it again). Any help how to run these kind of queries is helpful.

Comment: I have little experience working with JSON in R, but a library [such as this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/rjson.pdf), rjson, would be a good starting point.  You may build the JSON object you want, in an object oriented fashion, rather than by hand.

Comment: Thanks, will take alook. I added my library jsonlite, which uses named lists as body in POST.

Comment: Tim, I don't have anything against `rjson`, but is there anything in that package that provides functionality beyond what `jsonlite` does? If it were to add [`jq`-like](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filtering/modifying, then I'd say go for it, but otherwise I'm not certain it provides something new (enough).

Comment: Viitama, is there any reason you cannot do something like: `a <- fromJSON(json, simplifyDataFrame=FALSE); a$page <- 2; jsontxt <- toJSON(a)`?

Comment: r2evans: I added as.character(toJSON(a)) and it will give very close one. Then just removed brackets around page number. Thanks, very good comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r2vans comment with little bit extra will do the trick. Better responses are appreciated.

```
a <- fromJSON(json, simplifyDataFrame=TRUE)
a$page <- 1
jsontxt <- as.character(toJSON(a))
jsontxt  <- str_replace(jsontxt, "\\[", " ")
jsontxt  <- str_replace(jsontxt , "\\]", "")
```

jsontxt will go through with POST.